# How do you execute a python Wheel Class/Method(not a script) in Azure Data Factory using an Azure Databricks activity?

Tags: python, interop, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, python-wheel

Is it possible to execute a python Wheel Class/Method(not a script) in Azure Data Factory using an Azure Databricks activity like you would execute if it were a java packaged method in a .jar?  Unlike a script, this would have the ability to return a value(s), without doing something like burying them stdout.

I haven't been able to search anything and I tried using the jar activity with no luck which didn't surprise me but worth a try.

If not, what I am looking for is a way to use Azure Databricks compute and return a small set of values back from the python job.  I have successfully used the ADF activity for databricks python script.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add the wheel as a library on the cluster. Then create a .py file that imports the library and calls the method you need. 
Save the py file onto the dbfs volume.

Create a data factory pipeline that uses the python task and point it at your py file. You can pass in arguments as well.

You could also do this with a notebook that imports the library.

This blog post (and the series it is in) should help https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/9/20/building-pyspark-applications-as-a-wheel

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that has helped me to organize content in the wheel (.whl).

https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001jxOsgCAE/databricks-job-package-name-and-entrypoint-parameters-for-the-python-wheel-file

File structure:

```
| - setup.py
| - src
|  - __init__.py
|  - test1.py
|  - test2.py
```

Your setup.py content

```
 setup(    
      name="src",    
      packages = ['.src'],    
      description="demo",    
      version="0.1",
      ....
    )
```

And from the Databricks UI:

```
PackageName: src    
Entry_Point : print_name (Function inside __init__.py)
```